# Descargar solo una carpeta de github

Tags: git, github

Es posible descargar solamente una carpeta en especifico de un repositorio git, por ejemplo, si tengo un proyecto en github y el mismo está formado por varias carpetas, si en determinado momento deseo descargar solo una carpeta en especifico, ¿Es esto posible?'

Comment: Habría que hacerlo desde la consola. Acá te dejo un link de un script que desarrolló una persona para eso justamente: https://github.com/Decad/github-downloader/blob/master/github-downloader.sh

Answer (score 4):

La web [GitDown](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home) permite descargar la carpeta deseada de un proyecto solo hay que indicarle la url y listo, es cómodo y fácil.

[image: web gitdown] 
*Interfaz de la web `gitdown`*

Answer (score 2):

Desde Git 1.7.0 puedes hacer un **sparse-checkout**

tienes que iniciar un repositorio vacío primero con el remoto

```
git init <repositorio>
cd <repositorio>
git remote add -f origin <url>

// activar sparse-checkout
git config core.sparsecheckout true
```

Para definir que carpetas/archivos quieres recibir, tienes que definirlos en .gut/info/sparse-checkout, como por ejemplo (contenido del archivo sparse-checkout):

```
alguna/carpeta/
otra/carpeta/mas/
```

finalmente puedes actualizar tu repositorio local del remoto:

```
git pull origin master
```

Con git < versión 1.7.0 no hay posibilidades de hacer un check out parcial.